# How to add padding to a switch on an Appbar?

Tags: flutter

So I added a switch to my leading in my app bar. It added a left padding by default. Problem is this padding doesn’t match the rest of my body. I tried to wrap the switch with padding but it messed up the switch’s track. How to add padding to a switch on an Appbar?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it should work if you wrap it in a `SizedBox`. Then you can controll the Padding and size of it. With that the Switch will loose the default padding which was applied.

```
SizedBox(
    height: 24.0,
    width: 24.0,
    child: (...),
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppBar(
   leading: Switch(),
   titleSpacing: 0.0, //Use this how u like
   title: Text(""),
 ),
```